# How to combine 2 separate htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have 2 separate htaccess and i need to combine them into one but im not sure how to do it. These are my htaccess:

file 1 (the current one)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

file 2. (the new one)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Should i just put them together inside the same ifmodule? I already tried that and it didnt work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  just add the second into the first within the ifmodule excluding the below line....

RewriteEngine On

Comment: Happy to help. Please flag this answer as the correct one please. :)

Comment: I will do so as soon as this thing allows me to.